# Instantiate a generic list

Tags: c#, .net

I want to instantiate a generic list of objects like:

```
public static class TablesClass
{
    private static IList<Tables<T>> TablesInstance { get; set; }

    static TablesClass() => Tables = new List<Tables<T>>();
    public static void AddTable(Table<t> table) => Tables.Add(table);
}
```

I can't change Tables`<T>`, this is a nuget package class.

How may i achieve this? All i have tried just does not work (setting a type T to class, using object instead T and casts - not desired solution).

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You probably need to make `TablesClass` generic => `public static class TablesClass<T>`

Comment: But in this way i can't have multiple types on TablesInstance.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify how you actually want to use `TablesClass`. If you want a class-level generic field/property, you need a generic class

Comment: You need to tell the compiler what type `T` is supposed to be somewhere. If you want to be able to add different kinds of objects into the list, `T` must be a common type for all these objects like for example `object`.

Comment: Not desired solution looks to be the only solution you may have. 

Simply, if you want to be able to use the list with all sorts of Tables objects, you either need a base type that doesn't use generics or you need to use object instead of T. In either case, you will have no way to access to types in the list (e.g list's i'th elements Tables' type) compile time, so it doesn't really matter what path you choose to follow.

Comment: @JakeManet: `But in this way i can't have multiple types on TablesInstance.` You're misunderstanding the use case of generics. Every instantiated `List<T>` object (`List<string>`, `List<int>`, ...) will always only have **one** type. You can do things like `List<object>` to add many classes to your list but there are severe drawbacks to doing this (and it is generally unadvised to do so).

Comment: @Flater, you can add on a list objects like Tables<T>.

Comment: @JakeManet Not without having first defined T. There is a difference between the generic type of a class and the instantiated (concrete) type when this class is used

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Way much simple solution: `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: The dynamic word was cut off. I hope is not a waste of your time, might help others.

Answer (score 2):

`TablesClass` is not a generic class and you are not telling the compiler what type `T` is supposed to be somewhere.

If you want to be able to add different kinds of objects into the same `IList<Tables<T>>` list, `T` *must* be a common base type for all these objects.

For example, if you want to be able to add apples, pears and bananas to the list, the type parameter `T` may be specified as `Fruit` provided that `Fruit` is the base class for all these types.

Obviously you will need to cast from `Fruit` if you want to be able to access any member of an item in the list that is specific to a concrete implementation of `Fruit` class but this is inevitable. You don't throw a bunch of different kinds of fruits into a single basket and expect to be able to always pick up a specific fruit, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Your nuget class must be this style:

```
public abstract class Tables
{
}

//the Generic class must has a base, by which you can list them
public class Tables<T> : Tables // where T: something base class of your object
{
    //...
}
```

then your class must be:

```
public static class TablesClass
{
    //Search source code of your Nuget package, find its base class of Generic class, the list must be defined as its base
    private static IList<Tables> Tables { get; set; }

    static TablesClass()
    {
        Tables = new List<Tables>();
    }

    public static void AddTable(Tables table)
    {
        Tables.Add(table);
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Mains()
    {
        TablesClass.AddTable(new Tables<A>());
        TablesClass.AddTable(new Tables<B>());
        TablesClass.AddTable(new Tables<C>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this kind of thing you need to hold the references using `object`, but make a method that allows you to store and fetch each table using strong-typing.

Try a class like this:

```
public class Repository
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> _store
        = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>>();

    public void Store<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        if (!_store.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _store.Add(typeof(T), new Dictionary<string, object>());
        }
        _store[typeof(T)][key] = value;
    }

    public T Fetch<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)_store[typeof(T)][key];
    }

    public bool TryFetch<T>(string key, out T value)
    {
        var success = _store.ContainsKey(typeof(T)) && _store[typeof(T)].ContainsKey(key);
        value = success ? this.Fetch<T>(key) : default(T);
        return success;
    }

    public bool TryInject<T>(string key, Action<T> inject)
    {
        var success = this.TryFetch<T>(key, out T value);
        if (success)
        {
            inject(value);
        }
        return success;
    }       
}
```

Then you can strongly-type the objects into the repository (collection) and strongly-type fetching them out like this:

```
var repository = new Repository();

repository.Store("a", new TableA());
repository.Store("b", new TableB());
repository.Store("c", new TableC());
repository.Store("d", new TableD());

/* Somewhere else in your code */
TableA a = repository.Fetch<TableA>("a");
TableB b = repository.Fetch<TableB>("b");
TableC c = repository.Fetch<TableC>("c");
TableD d = repository.Fetch<TableD>("d");
```

The key value (i.e. "a") is optional - you can remove it from the code - but it is useful if you need to store more that one object of a specific type.